# Populate an entry box from sql within a Class

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to populate a default value in an entry box within a class using data pulled from a sql table, but I'm running into trouble. I pull the SQL query outside of the class and then try to access the variable within the class using a global variable. Then I set the global variable in the entry box using set(). Any insight into what I'm missing is greatly appreciated. EDIT: I updated this to the corrected code which reflects the suggested code change. This code now works.

```
# Data Audit GUI
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import pyodbc

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};""SERVER=xxxx;DATABASE=xxxx;""trusted_connection=yes;")

sql = """
SELECT title
FROM dbo.jobtable
WHERE jobid=4001
"""
Job = psql.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
Pyjobtitle = StringVar()
Pyjobtitle = Job['title'].values[0]

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        global Pyjobtitle
        self.ClassJobTitle = StringVar()
        self.JobTitle = Entry(root, width = 45, text = self.ClassJobTitle) # Job Title
        self.JobTitle.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, sticky = W)
        self.ClassJobTitle.set(Pyjobtitle)

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `psql.read_sql` returns a DataFrame so you'd need to do something in the realm of: `my_title = df['title'].values[0]`

Comment: global vars are evil.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: global variables aren't evil, it's the improper use of global variables that is evil.

Comment: @bernie has the correct answer. Should be converted from a comment so DataGuy can accept it.

Comment: @Cahit: ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `psql.read_sql` returns a `DataFrame` so you'd need to do something in the realm of:

```
my_title = df['title'].values[0]
```